# How to modify a prop and not reflect the change in parent

Tags: reactjs, immutability, react-props

I want to change some inner property of a prop. Props claim to be immutable, but when I change the value, the parent's state value is getting changed.I read that props are immutable. But changing the value is reflecting in parent.

```js
class ParentComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let property = {someProperty:'ABCD'};
        this.state={
            myState: property
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                Parent:{JSON.stringify(this.state.myState)}
                <ChildComp pState={this.state.myState} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ChildComp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        this.props.pState.someProperty = '1234';
        return(
            <div>
                Child:{JSON.stringify(this.props.pState)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

At the end, I see both the values are changed to 1234. In online fiddles, it is working as expected(ie., parent value is not changed.). But in my project, the parent is being changed.

How do I achieve this usecase, wherein I want to change some properties in props, and not reflect in the parent's state?

Comment: Deriving your data from `props` !== mutation

Comment: Got some bad news for you, it's not that simple. Stateless components can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/) dispatch an action and that action will be handed by a reducer that receives current state (your root props) and the action. This reducer will then return a new state (not mutate the current one) and react will re render.

Comment: @HMR - I don't have redux in my project currently. But if you feel this could serve my usecase, I can bring it in. Can you point me to any tutorial where I can start with?

Comment: The link in my comment and lots of videos on YouTube explaining how redux works and why to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that props are immutable

That's not true - you only should treat them as they were immutable. In other words, they are just regular javascript Objects and you should not mutate them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of the props, you should dump the props in the state first then do the mutation on that state.

Mutating props is not best practice. So your ChildComp should be like:

```
class ChildComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pState: props.pState,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { pState } = this.state.
        pState.someProperty = '1234';
        this.setState({
            pState,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>    
                Child:{JSON.stringify(this.state.pState)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't help either, it ended up changing the value of the parent.